# What indexes should be created for date subtraction in view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a view (`my_view`) with a calculated column (`days_since_my_date`) that gets the difference (in days) between today and a date column (`my_date` from `my_table`):

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT 'now'::text::date - my_date AS days_since_my_date,
...
FROM my_table;
```

What indexes (if any) do I need to optimize greater than/less than date queries on the view's calculated column (`days_since_my_date`)? I'm assuming they would need to be applied to the `my_date` column in `my_table`. The queries would be fairly simple, similar to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_view 
WHERE days_since_my_date >= 10;
```

A standard index created against `my_date`, like the one below, doesn't get hit during the above query:

```
CREATE INDEX my_date_idx on my_table(my_date);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't index your expression because it depends on a non-deterministic function.

Instead of comparing the constructed column, you should compare the indexed column against a constant (as of runtime):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    my_view
WHERE   my_date <= NOW() - '10 days'::INTERVAL
```

Comment: This makes sense. This way it takes advantage of the index, vs using the calculated column which wouldn't take advantage of any.